# Edit post locked notification dialog on edit post screen (post.php)... hook maybe?

Tags: posts

Creating a management application for my company and other utility companies... would be nice to remove the Preview button via php without a core hack...

I have to hack the core just a little anyhow and am keeping detailed records but if it is possible not to do this that would be very good.

Any feedback much appreciated

Comment: Are you using the Block Editor or the Classic Editor? The solution will depend on which editor you're supporting. Also, why do you "have" to hack core?

Comment: Because I am creating a project management system for my utility company and there are things that are better done via php than css or js.  I am using actions almost everywhere.  I think I have 2 hacks on the list.  I'll have to look them up and ask here if there is a better solution.  I have no worries thought of an update overwriting as I will have updates turned off so I can assess diff's as I need to... definitely trying to avoid it at all costs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the easiest approach is to hide that Preview button via CSS. Here is a snippet or you can add that style to a pre-existing wp-admin stylesheet that you might have already included.

```
add_action( 'admin_head-post.php', function(){
  echo '<style>';
    echo '.edit-post-header__settings .editor-post-preview { display: none !important; }';
  echo '</style>';
});
```

I tried digging through the core and I don't see any way to filter those links out.

Hope that helps!!

Comment: Thanks and I will give this a go then accept your answer... shame there is not a filter to take care of this but my use case is very unique one.